# understanding patch behavior

Tags: matlab, plot

I do not understand why `patch` does not follow the lines in this image:

[image: ex]

In fact, in the code I used, the lines and the patch share the same input variables `X` and `Y`:

```
clearvars
close all
clc

figure(1)
z=peaks(50);

% Create x,y coordinates of the data
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:50);

% Plot Data and the slicing curve
surf(z);
hold on

X=[1 21 35 47 29 25 8];
Y=[5 19 24 26 14 39 47];

plot3(X,Y,-10*ones(1,numel(X)),'r','linewidth',3);
plot3(X,Y,10*ones(1,numel(X)),'r','linewidth',3);

patch([X fliplr(X)],[Y fliplr(Y)],[-10*ones(1,numel(X)) 10*ones(1,numel(X))],...
    'r','FaceAlpha',0.21)

axis([0 50 0 50])
```

What am I messing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the wrong arguments to `patch`. The Matlab documentation says that

> If XData is a matrix, then each column represents the x-coordinates of a single face of the patch.

Thus, the patch data should look like this:

```
XData= [
X(1) X(2) ... and so on
X(2) X(3)
X(2) X(3)
X(1) X(2)];

YData= [
Y(1) Y(2) ... 
Y(2) Y(3)
Y(2) Y(3)
Y(1) Y(2)];

ZData= [
-10 -10 ...
-10 -10
 10 10
 10 10];
```

You can use `patch` this way:

```
patch([X(1:end-1);X(2:end);X(2:end);X(1:end-1)],[Y(1:end-1);Y(2:end);Y(2:end);Y(1:end-1)],...
    [-10*ones(1,numel(X)-1);-10*ones(1,numel(X)-1);10*ones(1,numel(X)-1);10*ones(1,numel(X)-1)],...
    'r','FaceAlpha',0.21)
```

or you can use `surf`:

```
surf([X;X],[Y;Y],[-10*ones(1,numel(X)) ;10*ones(1,numel(X))],'FaceAlpha',0.21);
```